# Why does the Order of GROUPBY and ORDERBY matter in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

In the Amazon Redshift Documentation, they advise to have ordering in the ORDERBY and GROUPBY clauses:

> If you use both GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses, make sure you put the columns in the same order in both. That is, use the following approach:
>
> `group by a, b, c`
>
> `order by a, b, c`
>
> Don't use this approach:
>
> `group by b, c, a`
>
> `order by a, b, c`

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_designing-queries-best-practices.html

They don't explain why! Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`GROUP BY` implicitly requires the data to be sorted. If your `ORDER BY` is different the data will have to be sorted ***twice***.

And, since Redshift distributes it's data among multiple nodes, that may mean the data has to be *sent to all nodes twice*.

If the data set being returned by `GROUP BY` is small (10s or 100s of rows) you won't notice, but if it's large (millions of rows) it will be very slow.

Comment: why does group by require data to be sorted?

Comment: `GROUP BY` basically means "compress duplicates of this column into a single row", right? The duplicates are found by sorting the data.

Comment: Couldn't it find duplicates it some other way like via a hashmap?

Comment: is this only a redshift thing or group by done this way with all databases?

Comment: Some databases do use a hashmap but many, e.g., SQL Server, use sort AFAIK. Redshift can skip sort operations when the sort is on the `SORTKEY` and the table is 100% sorted. Sort based `GROUP BY` may have been preferred for that reason.

Comment: neato. After Googling around, it seems that Redshift tries to do a Sort Join if possible , if not it will do a Merge Join